# How can I search for a line of text in multiple lines of text using a Python single-liner?

Tags: python, search, line

I've got text of multiple lines stored in a string. I want to get the first line of that string in which there is some specific bit of text. How could this be done in one line of code?

Here's my attempt so far:

```
length_line = [line if "Length" in line for line in output.split("\n")][0]
```

Comment: You can use `next(line for line in output.split("\n") if "Length" in line)`

Comment: Ah, very nice. Thanks for that. I hadn't considered using `next`.

Comment: Do not forget to add a default value if necessary. ;)